# Counting rows by category-filter during fetching of categories from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I have two tables in my database

```
table: products                   table: companies
+-----------+------------+        +------+------------+
| name      | company_id |        | id   | name       |
+-----------+------------+        +------+------------+
|Product 1  | 1          |        | 1    | Company 1  |
|Product 2  | 1          |        | 2    | Company 2  |   
|Product 3  | 3          |        | 3    | Company 3  |
|Product 4  | 1          |        | 4    | Company 4  |
|Product 5  | 1          |        | ...               |
|Product 6  | 3          |        +------+------------+
|Product 7  | 2          |
|...                     |
+-----------+------------+
```

Now I have to make **company-selector** (filtering products by company) using HTML `SELECT` element with names of all companies from table `companies` and `COUNT` of products after company name in the list.

So, my goal is to get `SELECT` options like this:

- Company 1 (4)
- Company 2 (1)
- Company 3 (2)
- Company 4 (0)

*(note: counts inside the brackets are from example above)*

### What have I tried so far?

I was using `mysql_*` functions earlier and later it was `mysqli` procedural model. I can do this manually with one query for companies and another one inside `while` block to get `COUNT` of elements (filtered by current company's id in the loop). Now I'm trying to work with `PDO object` which is something new for me and I'm not very familiar with it.

### Question

Is it somehow possible to get `COUNT` with one query (using `JOINs` or something)? If not, how I can do it with query inside the loop (old way) using my `$dbPDO` object? Or any other way?

I've looked some examples here but nothing could adapt to fit my requirements. Maybe I missed something but working with PDO is still painful for me (and I must learn it ASAP).

Looking at my own question, I don't think it's something hard, but the worst thing, I **can't find solution** by myself.

At the end, I have solution in `mysqli`, just I don't like it so much and think there's easier way of making this task done!

I thought this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803905/counting-all-the-posts-belonging-to-a-category-and-its-subcategories) is something I need but still don't understand that query in answer.

So far I have this code and have no idea how to make it counts products:

```
  $dbPDO = new PDO('mysql:dbname=comixdb;host=localhost', 'root', '');
  $sel_cat = ''; # selector HTML
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name";
  foreach ($dbPDO->query($sql) as $row) {
    $sel_cat .= "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['name']}</option>";
    }
  $sel_cat = "<select><option value=\"*\">All categories</option>$sel_cat</select>";

  echo $sel_cat;
```

Hope I've clarified question enough. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need can be done in SQL:

```
SELECT companies.name, SUM(IF(company_id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS products
    FROM companies
    LEFT JOIN products ON (companies.id = products.company_id)
    GROUP BY companies.id;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that all companies get selected, and the `SUM` ensures that the count is correct (a simple `COUNT` would return 1 for companies with no products).

Comment: hm, this promises... let me try

Comment: Found serious problem, this QUERY returns JUST ONE company with NO products, rest of them are missing. Everything's fine for companies with some products.

Comment: Let me check with some sample data. Back in a few minutes.

Comment: No need of sample data. Stupid error in copy and paste. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah, that GROUP BY change helped ;) Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for the mishap. I *had* tested the code, but the final version looked the same since I only had *one* company with no products in my test set (*palm, meet face*).